Integral involving fractional powers and logarithmic functions
Can any of following indefinite integrals be expressed in terms of known functions
$$
I_1(a,b,c,z)=\int \frac{z^b (1+\alpha\,z)^c}{(1-z)^{a}} \log  z\,{\rm d}z\quad\text{and}\quad I_2(a,b,z)=\int z^a(1-\alpha\,z)^b \log(1+z)\,{\rm d}z
$$
with $a,b,c,\alpha$ constants?
I was able to express the integral above in terms of derivatives of Appell functions with respect to parameters. But I was wondering if a simpler form exists in terms of Appell functions only.

Is there a domain of integration in which you are interested @user12588 ?

You can just evaluate $\int \frac{z^b(1+\alpha,z)^c }{(1-z)^{a}} \log  zdz$ after expanding the $1+\beta,z$ into 2 integrals

@Sam Not really. At the moment I want to understand what can be done in general. After some research, I managed to obtain the above as a Kampé de Fériet function (this is to be expected, given that we can easily express the integral above in terms of derivatives of Appel functions with respect to its parameters).

@Tyma Gaidash - that is correct. I just amended the question to accommodate your comment.

Do we know anything about the constants? @user12588 , are they all positive? Integers?

@Sam We can take the constants to be positive and real.

Just looking at the criteria for the constants, I had a feeling that most integrals of the above two classes are precisely non-elementary and cannot be expressed in terms of any named functions in the mathematical literature. However, I plugged them into WolframAlpha just in case to actually confirm this, and it appears that that assumption is correct.
